# Implementing CoreData in SwiftUI with a popOver

Tags: core-data, swiftui, xcode12

I have poured over this for hours and I can say with 99% certainty that I know what is breaking but I don't know why or how to fix it.

```
    @State private var timeSet = false {
        willSet {
            if newValue {
                flyingHours = timeMachine.calculateTotalFlightHours()
            }
        }
    }
```

The code above stops working when I use
`AddSortie().environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)`
with the button to trigger the popover.  **timeSet** never becomes true, or if it does it very quickly resets to false.
However, by leaving off the .environment
`AddSortie()`
**timeSet** does become true at the appropriate time and the app works as expected... Except without .environmtnt I can not save to CoreData.
Any ideas?
For what it's worth I am working in XCode 12 Beta 2
Thanks

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks. I’ll update the post with more code. I was just trying to stick to the core of the issue.